# callback function wont run when its called

Tags: ajax, callback

```
ajax : function(typ,url,callback) {

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xml.onreadystatechange = function(callback) {

            if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
                    callback();
            }
        }
            xml.open(typ,url,true);
            xml.send();
    }

  }

 //Function being called
window.onload = function() {    
    JS.ajax("GET","/server/chkEmail.php?email=email@email.com",function()                       { 
        alert(xml.responseText);
    });
}
```

It throws the error saying:

Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a functionxml.onreadystatechange @
global.js:30

Any ideas?

I fixed it by passing the data variable through the onreadystatechange function and calling it in the callback function.

```
ajax : function(typ,url,callback) {

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xml.onreadystatechange = function(data) {

            if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
                    var data = xml.responseText;
                    callback(data);
            }
        };
            xml.open(typ,url,true);
            xml.send();
    }

}

window.onload = function() {    
    JS.ajax("GET","/server/chkEmail.php?  email=jonwcode@gmail.com",function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: What does your browser's debug console say?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: Anyone have any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
        callback();
    }
};
```

Notice that the [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) function doesn't take any parameters whereas in your code you have passed it a parameter with the name `callback` which will override the `callback` variable from the outer scope.

---

UPDATE:

It looks like you have improperly scoped the `xml` variable and it isn't available in your AJAX callback. I strongly recommend you reading more about javascript variables scope. Here's how you could make the `xml` variable visible:

```
var xml = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if (xml == null) {
    alert('Sorry, your browser doesn\'t seem to support AJAX - please upgrade to a modern browser');
} else {
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            var data = xml.responseText;
            callback(data);
        }
    };

    xml.open(typ,url,true);
    xml.send();
}
```

Comment: Throws another error. Uncaught ReferenceError: xml is not defined

Comment: Thats for the other page in which I'm calling the callback function.

Comment: The reason you are getting this error is because you have incorrectly scoped your `xml` variable. See my updated answer for an example on how to fix that.